# ConstraintLayout applying margin bottom to a view, also applies it to the top of the view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I have a `TextView`, below it an `EditText` and below it another `TextView`. When I apply a bottom margin of 12 dp to the `EditText`, it's applied but it also applies to the top of the view. I don't know if this is the way `ConstraintLayout` works. `marginTop` works as expected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEOUz.jpg

Comment: can you show your xml code..?

Comment: Bro I just added a screenshot pls take a look

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see in your attachment you are creating a vertical chain but you didn't restrain your "description" to the bottom. This could cause issues since the constraint layout doesn't know where the chain ends. make sure you add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` or whatever view you need as a bottom chain constraint on the description TextView.

I recreated your example and there is mirror margin for the edit text.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="edit text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/description"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimaryLight"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
```

You can play around with the chainStyle to see which fits best your needs.